# Search string syntax for Restrict method

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to pull a set of five emails from a specified Outlook folder based on two conditions - the (partial) subject line, and received between two specified dates. I've used the `Items.Restrict` method in the past for a similar task, filtering only on the partial subject line, but I'm struggling with including the dates as well.

My template, the line that works correctly, looks thus:

```
strFilter = "@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:subject"" like '%" & strSubject & "%'"
Set itmFiltered = fld.Items.Restrict(strFilter)
```

I've tried including the dates in various ways. Based on the help file, I thought something like this would work:

```
strFilter = "@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:subject"" like '%" & strSubject & "%'"
If Len(strStart) <> 0 then
    strfilter = strfilter & " AND ""urn:schemas:httpmail:Received:"" >='" & strStart & "'"
End If

set itmFiltered = fld.Items.Restrict(strfilter)
```

Error, every time.

I also tried setting it to just filter by the date, without including the subject line, like this:

```
strFilter = "@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:Received: >=""'" & strStart & "'"
```

Again, no luck.

So, my questions:

**What syntax do I need to use the Items.Restrict method to filter by date?**

**And what syntax do I need to use the Items.Restrict method to filter by multiple fields?**

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have an `":"` at the end of`""urn:schemas:httpmail:Received:""`. Secondly, there is no such DASL name. Did you mean `"datereceived"`?

You need to use `"urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"` or `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E060040"`. Use [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) to look up a DASL property name - click IMessage button, select the property, look at the DASL edit box.